# Passing strange text as variables via post method in php

Tags: php, javascript, html, unicode

I have an odd problem. Our company collects data and we use a HORRIBLE piece of software to handle all of our phone interviewing. It uses binary files instead of SQL and uses no compression. As of right now we have to manually run all reports for the clients. I am working on building a web interface to our data and common reports.

Now I need to pass whats called a "select statement" from the web to the server and I do this with php post method. The problem is that web browsers don't seem to like some of the characters that have to be used in select statements. I have tried encoding them but then the browsers auto uncode them back to plain text when they are hyperlinks.

Here are some example select statements.

```
[3023.2#1] 
[3023.2$] = "1"
[3023.2<>1]
[500.10$] = "Name"
```

And the url would look something like

```
CustomReport.php?type=1&select="[3023.2#1]"
```

The problem I have is that different select statements break the website depending on quotes used. select=[3023.2<>1] wont work but select="[3023.2<>1]" does. BUT if I do select=[3023.2#1] it will work and using quotes will break it. And when it breaks it neither WebDev toolbar nor FireBug report any errors but its obvious my DIVs are all messed up.

I should also add that nowhere is the select statement displayed on the site, it is only used in php as part of an exec command so I'm really confused as to why this breaks my site.

/Ropes End 
//Probably something stupid

Comment: That's not a POST method btw.

Comment: Just because I can't bear it, I have to ask you to *please ensure that you are properly sanitizing any $_GET or $_POST variables before using them with exec()*, or anywhere else for that matter. Aside from that, please describe how/what methods you have "tried encoding them" with.

Comment: ... and you wouldn't have this kind of problem at all if you really use POST :D

Comment: Also don't worry about the security guys i have it running on a locked down account on a special dedicated server that only only 5 ips can connect as of now AND it sanitizes everything and submission to the DB AND retrieval (just in case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to research [rawurlencode](http://php.net/rawurlencode) and [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities). They should help you immensely.

*Aside: The note from anonymous to be cautious passing executable commands over urls MUST be heeded. It sounds like your application is not on the public web, but if it is you need to be mindful of the security issues associated with that.*

```
<?php 

$select_statements = array(
    '[3023.2#1]',
    '[3023.2$] = "1"',
    '[3023.2<>1]',
    '[500.10$] = "Name"',
);

foreach ($select_statements as $ss) {
    print htmlentities($ss);
    print "<br>";
    $url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?type=1&amp;select=" . rawurlencode($ss);
    print "<a href=\"{$url}\">{$url}</a>";  
    print "<br>";
    print "<br>";
}

print htmlentities($_GET['select']);

?>
```

Results (for me):

> [3023.2#1]
>   /CustomReport.php?type=1&select=%5B3023.2%231%5D
>
> [3023.2$] = "1"
>   /CustomReport.php?type=1&select=%5B3023.2%24%5D%20%3D%20%221%22
>
> [3023.2<>1]
>   /CustomReport.php?type=1&select=%5B3023.2%3C%3E1%5D
>
> [500.10$] = "Name"
>   /CustomReport.php?type=1&select=%5B500.10%24%5D%20%3D%20%22Name%22

And if I click on a link I will also see whichever select I put in. Properly put into html entities, of course.

Comment: Whats the difference from urlencode vs rawurlencode php.net only mentioned is that raw uses rf1738 and i have no clue what that standard is.

Comment: The RFC http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738 -- difficult reading. But compare http://php.net/urlencode and http://php.net/rawurlencode and it's major diff is for spaces converted to "+" versus "%20". Also keep in mind many browsers these days will decode the "%xx" numbers for you.

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with bash and then the bash error returned some of the <> text and broke the divs. But now that everything is encoded it seems a few of my other problems have been fixed. Thanks for all your help artlung!!

Answer (score 1):

And you have tried url-encoding only the select part?

```
$queryString = 'select=' . urlencode($select);
```

Answer (score 0):

For each of the parameters, you should use `urlencode` to escape the characters:

```
$select = urlencode("[3023.2#1]");
```

via https://www.php.net/urlencode

Comment: The PHP documentation favors rawurlencode() over urlencode() because of urlencode uses the older "space" turns into a "plus sign" rather than "%20" -- see http://us2.php.net/rawurlencode

Answer (score 0):

Try using the urlencode/urldecode functions on your select strings. This should encode all the weird characters correctly.

also be careful with the exec command. Its convenient but dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

You could also forgo using POST. Instead, store the statement in a session variable, database, or temp file, then retrieve for processing on the next page.

If you use a database, use a binary type text field with utf8 encoding, which should allow you to handle strange characters.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the values on the GUI to build your query statement directly? You should have all of these "queries" hiding on the server in a map to sane values and only except the sane values from the web client:

```
 $queries = Array(
       'meaningfulname1' => '[3023.2#1]',
       'meaningfulname2' => '[3023.2$] = "1"',
       'meaningfulname3' => '[3023.2<>1]',
       'meaningfulname4' => '[500.10$] = "Name"',
 );
```

Then your URL is simply

```
 CustomReport.php?type=1&select=meaningfulname1
```

Now you can easily translate "meaningfulname1" into the proper code sequence needed by your software and you aren't exposing the backend craziness to the browser. This also means if you somehow fix your backend to use some other query language (like SQL) you don't need to recode the GUI layer. It still requests meaningfulname1.